# Handling background notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app and decided to use Firebase's cloud messaging. The problem I have is that I have no idea how to handle the notification data I get. As far as I know, when you open the notification from background you get intent with the data sent from server in launcher activity. So I have something like this in my launcher activity:

```
Intent intentOpen;
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

    if(message != null) {
            intentOpen = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            if (message.equals(this.getResources().getString(R.string.new_shared_file))) {
                intentOpen.putExtra(MainActivity.nType, "SHARING");
            } else {
                intentOpen.putExtra(MainActivity.nType, "SERVICES");
            }
        }
    }
```

And in my main activity I want to get the nType to determine which fragment should app open:

```
public static String nType = "notification_type";

if (getIntent().hasExtra(nType)) {
        String notification = getIntent().getStringExtra(nType);
        if (notification.equals("SHARING")) {
            displayView(R.id.nav_shared_files);
        } else {
            displayView(R.id.nav_account);
        }
    } else if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        displayView(R.id.nav_online_files);
    }
```

So how do I get the String across to the main activity (which I get to after two other activities). Or is there some other way (like from server side) to get the String to the main activity?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: You have used intent to shared data already, and i don't seems to understand the problem. please can you provide the error you are getting when you run the code?

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem is that I don't get anything from "nType" in main activity

Comment: You are building intentOpen but are you actually sending it? Like: startActivity(intentOpen);

Comment: I tried, but the result was the same, sadly.

Comment: Also, I do not intend to start that activity (MainActivity) right away, as I need to do other things too (like login and etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your launcher activity you will get message like this if you send message from console as additional filed  option in firebase console:[image]

Regarding image up, you get image as custom data field, otherwise you will not get message in you case. In case if you app is in foreground, you will get your notification data in method onReceiveMessage inside FirebaseNotificationService.

Intent intentOpen;
    String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image"); // or imageUrl

Sending data to other activities must be done over intent arguments, if you want to go this way, you should always put whatever arguments you need to intent when starting next activity. And of course you can choose some other ways to passing data to other activities.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there other ways of passing data straight into the activity I want? Because after the launch activity I go through other two activities and only then arrive at my main activity, so will I need to carry the data across all those activities too? Also, isn't there a thing, where you could specify which activity gets the message (from background) , because I would like it to be done in MainActivity, not LaunchActivity.

Comment: To add to the lastquestion: I do not want to launch the main activity immediately (as you could do by adding click_action to notification) I just want that all message handling would be done there, not in launcher.

Comment: You can't define in which activity you will get data, firebase automatically choose launcher activity. Of course this is valid if application is in background, if is in foreground, you will get callback in onMessageReceived (inside FirebaseNotificationService) and from there you can define which activity you want to run, or show notification. Also there is way to trigger onMessageReceived all the time, with sending firebase push trough api call, with only "data" object in it..

Comment: Passing data to only requested activity can be done with Singletons, or PublishSubjects over RxJava, defined in AppController.. or maybe you can also use database, anyway there are many ways to do this, depends on your requirement.

Comment: Also, could you give me a link to a good example of using singleton to pass the data from one activity to another?

Answer (score 2):

Sure for example you can create enum class with instance:

```
public enum DataManager {
        INSTANCE;
        private String data;

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

So in first activity when you get data you call:

```
DataManager.INSTANCE.setData("whateverdata");
```

And in activity you need data you just call:

```
String savedData = DataManager.INSTANCE.getData();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me greatly and saved a lot of time